# Scroll part of page till the very last section in the div in selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I have scenario where a check box will be enabled only when scroll section of div is fully scrolled. 
Using above techniques and all the lookups I was able to scroll to last element of the div. But the problem is, there is some margin/padding which is left between last element and the scrolling div end section which is not making the checkbox to be enabled. If I give

```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath"));
((JavascriptExecutor) 
 driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

I am able to kind of focus on the scrolling div section, but not able to scroll.

```
  Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
  actions.moveToElement(element);
  actions.perform();
```

Here, am able to move to last element of the div. but not end of scrolling div so, checkbox is still disabled.

```
  js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,100);")
```

is scrolling the entire window which is expected. So, is there a way to explicitly scroll part of div?

Is there any tweaks that can be done in order to make the checkbox enabled?

Comment: Can you lend me the website URL please?

Answer (score 0):

First, Let's note some key ideas

key difference between `scrollTo` & `scrollBy` is that

- `scrollTo` scrolls to a specific part of the website as you expect.
- `scrollBy` scrolls to specific part FROM the current position.

You need to `scrollTo` not `scrollBy`, now let's scroll to the end of your `div`

Second important note is that the padding is considered a part of the element unlike margin, if you get an element's height, the padding is in that height

now get your element as a javascript object and assign it to a variable.

so Assign this

```
driver.executeScript("const myElem = document.getElementById('ELEMENT_ID'); return myElem")
```

to a WebElement object as this code will return your element, if it has no ID use any other JS method to get your element class  or whatever.

we called it myElem so we can still refernce it with JS with that name, execute this on the driver

```
window.scrollTo(0, myElem.offsetTop + myElem.offsetHeight )
```

this scrolls to "your element's top coordinate" + "your element's height" which is just below it.

if the website was smart enough to detect that this scrolling was robotic, you can use

```
window.scrollTo({
  top: myElem.offsetTop + myElem.offsetHeight,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

if there's still margin, get it the same way then add it to the top offset.